# Problem with using MPI_SENDRECV with 4 threads

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

As a minimal problem, I'm trying to send an integer between 4 processors: 0 -> 3 (rank `0` sends to and receives from rank `3`), 2 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 0. It never finishes execution and hangs, probably waiting for the response from other threads.

I'm compiling the code with `mpif90 ...` and running with `mpiexec -np 4 ...`. Below is the minimal snippet:

```
program sendrecv
  implicit none
  include "mpif.h"
  integer :: foo, bar
  integer :: mpi_rank, mpi_size, ierr
  integer :: mpi_sendto, mpi_recvfrom
  integer :: istat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), status, i

  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_size, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, mpi_rank, ierr)
  print *, "SENDING..."

  if (mpi_rank .eq. 0) then
    mpi_sendto = 3; mpi_recvfrom = 3
  else if (mpi_rank .eq. 1) then
    mpi_sendto = 2; mpi_recvfrom = 2
  else if (mpi_rank .eq. 2) then
    mpi_sendto = 1; mpi_recvfrom = 1
  else
    mpi_sendto = 0; mpi_recvfrom = 0
  end if

  foo = mpi_rank
  do i = 1, 5
    foo = mpi_rank
    call MPI_SENDRECV(foo, 1,&
                    & MPI_INTEGER, mpi_sendto, mpi_rank * 10 + i,&
                    & bar, 1,&
                    & MPI_INTEGER, mpi_recvfrom, mpi_rank * 10 + i,&
                    & MPI_COMM_WORLD, istat, ierr)
  end do

  print *, "...DONE"
  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end
```

I don't really understand why this program hangs, maybe I'm missing something or doing something really wrong. If I understand correctly, `MPI_SENDRECV` is just non-blocking `send` and `recv` with two `wait`-s. In that case, say, if `rank=0` sends to `rank=3` it shouldn't have any problem receiving from it, right?

I tried sending/receiving from different threads, i.e., doing this:

```
  if (mpi_rank .eq. 0) then
    mpi_sendto = 1; mpi_recvfrom = 3
  else if (mpi_rank .eq. 1) then
    mpi_sendto = 2; mpi_recvfrom = 0
  else if (mpi_rank .eq. 2) then
    mpi_sendto = 3; mpi_recvfrom = 1
  else
    mpi_sendto = 0; mpi_recvfrom = 2
  end if
```

still not working.

**UPD** As it was pointed out, tags should be the same when doing `SENDRECV`, however In case when doing this call within a loop, similar tags don't help much (see modified code). Old version:

```
call MPI_SENDRECV(foo, 1,&
                    & MPI_INTEGER, mpi_sendto, 200,&
                    & bar, 1,&
                    & MPI_INTEGER, mpi_recvfrom, 100,&
                    & MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierr)
```

**UPD#2** Actually, if anyone is interested, I found a [discussion](https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/send_isend_or_sendrecv) exactly about the problem I have on why `SENDRECV`-s may deadlock sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "thread" is misleading here, you should talk about MPI task or MPI process (both are equivalent).

The root cause is a tag mismatch. You send with tag `200` but receive with tag `100`.

Also, you should use `istat` instead of `status` as the status argument of `MPI_Sendrecv()`.

Here is how you can fix your program

```
call MPI_SENDRECV(foo, 1,&
                & MPI_INTEGER, mpi_sendto, 200,&
                & bar, 1,&
                & MPI_INTEGER, mpi_recvfrom, 200,&
                & MPI_COMM_WORLD, istat, ierr)
```

Comment: That is true, thanks! Sorry, I actually had in mind a `SENDRECV` call from within a loop. In that case same tags don't seem to work. :\

Comment: Ok, nvm. I found the problem. It was the `status` size, it was probably overflowing over `MPI_STATUS_SIZE` and modifying other variables it shouldn't in the `SENDRECV` call. Using `istat` worked. Thanks! The bastard compiler didn't even bother warning me :\

Comment: You are more likely to get this kind of warnings if you `use mpi` instead of `include 'mpif.h'`. `use mpi_f08` is even better (but requires some compiler support and might require a few code changes too).